# HTML Form (with PHP) requires I press submit button twice before it takes me to the action form

Tags: php, forms

I'm new to PHP so please bear with me.
I'm trying to decide the action based on the given input.
Given below is the code I've written for this simple task

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>SAMPLE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit_button']))
        {
            if($_POST['name_field'] === "USERA")
            {
               echo "output.php";
            }
            else
            {
               echo "wronguser.php";
            }
        }
        ?>">
        Username : <input type="text" name="name_field" value="<?php
        if(!isset($_POST['name_field']) || $_POST['name_field']=== "")
        {
        echo "Enter Something" ;
        }
        ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="SUBMIT BUTTON !">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I want the form to redirect to "output.php" if the user is "USERA" or "wrongouput.php" for any other user name entered. Although it works as expected, I'm redirected to the right page only when I press the submit button the 2nd time.

Why is this ?

Also, reloading the page doesn't seem to bring back the original page with the text field containing the default "Enter Something" text. I have to run it all over again from the IDE.

Why is this ?

Comment: Its totally logic. you've a `action="` and then look at your first IF-condition. `(isset($_POST['submit_button'])` and since submit_button isn't set, the code generated for your form is `<form method="post" action="">` - so there's no action.

Comment: what did you expect, abusing the `action` like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a different approach

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_button']))
    {
        if($_POST['name_field'] === "USERA")
        {
           require_once("output.php");
        }
        else
        {
           require_once("wronguser.php");
        }
    }
    else
    {
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>SAMPLE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="">
        Username : <input type="text" name="name_field" value="<?php
        if(!isset($_POST['name_field']) || $_POST['name_field']=== "")
        {
        echo "Enter Something" ;
        }
        ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="SUBMIT BUTTON !">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your code out of the action, make the action for the form self so it fires on itself, then put your PHP above all the HTML at the top of the file. That'll stop the double click issue.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit_button']))
        {
            if($_POST['name_field'] === "USERA")
            {
               echo "output.php";
            }
            else
            {
               echo "wronguser.php";
            }
        }
        ?>">
        Username : <input type="text" name="name_field" value="<?php
        if(!isset($_POST['name_field']) || $_POST['name_field']=== "")
        {
        echo "Enter Something" ;
        }

 ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>SAMPLE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method='post' action="<?php $SERVER['PHPSELF']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="SUBMIT BUTTON !">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```